# [opengl]get world position after rotate object by pivot

Tags: opengl, rotate

I need to rotate an object around a pivot,so I use this theory:

1. Translate the object to Pivot position
2. Rotate the object
3. Translate back the object from Pivot position

everything works fine,I can successfully rotate the object by a fixed point.
but the problem is, I lose control of the world position of the object.how can I calculate the world position?

Comment: After the modifications, where is your object except in world position, isn't what you just calculated? I don't get what you need.

Comment: my object contains several member variables: mTransform,mPosition,mRotation..., if I translate the object,I will update the mPosition' xyz value.you know, glm Library only updates our transform matrix, it won't tell us the position changes after we rotate the matrix

Comment: The 4th column of the mTransform is mPosition.

Comment: awesome! I can't believe there's such a simple way to calculate the position vector,thank you man! please let us know if there are easier way to get the other transform components

Answer (score 0):

A scene graph node typically stores this kind of information:

- Parent node (reference)
- Transform (matrix) OR ( translation (matrix) AND rotation (matrix) [AND scale (matrix)] )
- Children nodes (references)

To determine the final position of a node, you compute the transformation of the node, then calculate the transformation of each of the parents, in order, up to the root of the scene graph.

So you don't "lose" information, it's there and it's computed on a per-need basis.